# In the Dissolve tab for smoke simulations is the ‘time’ seconds or frames?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, gpu, fire

I’m currently testing out smoke and fire simulations and I came across the ‘Dissolve’ tab, and I’m not sure whether ‘time’ means frames or seconds.

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/iqDsfYb) is from the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/physics/smoke/types/domain.html#settings). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot!